# android database adding more than needed

Tags: android, sqlite

```
private static String[] FROM = { _ID, DESCRIPTION, DATE, TITLE };
    //private static String ORDER_BY = _ID + " DESC" ;
    private Cursor getEvents() {
    // Perform a managed query. The Activity will handle closing
    // and re-querying the cursor when needed.
    SQLiteDatabase db = post.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null,
    null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
    }    



private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
             // Stuff them all into a big string
             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(
             "Saved events:\n" );
             while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
             // Could use getColumnIndexOrThrow() to get indexes
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
             String description = cursor.getString(1);
             String date = cursor.getString(2);
             String title = cursor.getString(3);

         builder.append(id).append(": " );
             builder.append(description).append(": " );
             builder.append(date).append(": " );
             builder.append(title).append("\n" );

         }
             // Display on the screen
             tv.setText(builder);
             this.setContentView(tv);

         }
```

So the showEvents function which is supposed to display the database is displaying a larger database than I created.  It is showing 19 rows, yet I only called the insertorthrow function twice so it should have two rows, so I don't know how it can have more than 19 rows.  I feel the problem may lie in my getEvents() function or showEvents() function which returns the cursor.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The database will be persistent so you may be adding rows every time yoou try?  Try uninstalling and starting from scratch.

Comment: derp, yes thats what happened

Answer (score 0):

Using db shell go to the location and delete the database .